# missing Plug-in for TunesViewer

Tags: plugins

I installed TunesViewer from software center, and i am having this problem seeing TV show it says:

```
   Missing Plug-in
```

I downloaded evasion for TunesViewer but can not install it when it says:

```
   You must install iTunes for this program to work
```

could this not work for TunesViewer,  or should I find a hole other plug-in to make this work, can some one please help.

Comment: This has been discussed, See https://github.com/rbrito/tunesviewer/pull/39  Can you provide a specific link (TV shows are not supported BTW, preview might *possibly* work)? Also what is "evasion for Tunesviewer"?

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be all fixed in Tunesviewer 1.5.2 :)